# How can I add support for a + (plus sign) in this email validation regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

This is a regular expression I found online that seems to do a great job at simple email address validation. The problem is it doesn't allow + in the email, like `my+email@domain.com`. I'm not great at regex, so how can I add support for a + without breaking the whole thing?

```
var regex = new RegExp( /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i );
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/4736/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/3001761

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to use the `RegExp` constructor if you're using the `/exp/i` literal notation.

Comment: Where do you need to support the + sign in the middle or in the start or at any position ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the second `[\w-]+` to `[+\w-]+`

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! You correctly answered my question based on my example. I'll mark as accepted once the time limit is up. One thing I forgot though is that it's valid for the `+` to be the first character also. I also changed the first `[\w-]+` to `[+\w-]+` and that seems to allow `+` as the first character as well. Is that the correct way to do this?

Comment: Yep! Good catch too!

Answer (score 0):

```
([+\w0-9._-]+@[\w0-9._-]+\.[\w0-9_-]+)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 